# Multiple route files are not directing to the absolute path but appending new path at last of the existing path, hence unable to complete GET request

Tags: node.js, express

I have two routes and when i am trying to access files alternately from these routes, it ends up giving error (can not `GET /user/user/viewUser`).

following is the case:

### app.js file

```
var home = require('./routes/index');
    app.use('/', home);

var user = require('./routes/userRoutes');
    app.use('/user', user);
```

So if I make a call for the path with `/user/createNewUser` this page is accessed but when i try to access another path using `/user`, I get an error `Cannot GET /user/user/viewUser` coz system appends new path at the last rather than starting from absolute path.

Comment: Change the way you are accessing the path. Where are you using these?

Comment: I mean to say that when another path /user/viewUser is tried to accessed it gets appended to the existing path and the path becomes /user/user/viewUser and hence I get an error 'Cannot GET /user/user/viewUser'

Comment: Yeah, but where and how are you accessing these paths? Do you have some frontend? If so add that to the question

Comment: Yes, I am accessing it from front end.

Comment: Yes, I am accessing it from front end.

Comment: <a class="headerBtn dropdown-item" href="user/viewCreateUser">Create User</a>

Comment: <a class="headerBtn dropdown-item" href="user/viewUser">View Users</a>

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative paths in your anchor tags. Try using absolute paths:

`<a class="headerBtn dropdown-item" href="/user/viewCreateUser">Create User</a>`

`<a class="headerBtn dropdown-item" href="/user/viewUser">View Users</a>`

or

`<a class="headerBtn dropdown-item" href="YOUR_DOMAIN_URL/user/viewUser">View Users</a>`

**Update**

You can use javascript to select your anchor tags and give them a dynamic href attribute. For example:

```
const DOMAIN_URL = 'YOUR_URL';
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.href = `${DOMAIN_URL}/user/viewUser`;
});
```

Now this will change the `href` of the first anchor tag it finds so you should query for the ones you want and assign them dynamic `href` values.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, the path you have suggested works, but I want to know that I have around 10 anchor tags on the front end, do i have to add domain url to all of them

Comment: @mohitkumar - Yeah you should. You can export that to a constant and use it everywhere.

Comment: @ Ramesh .... How do we do that.... "export to a constant and use it everywhere"

Comment: @mohitkumar Updated my answer. There are multiple other ways to do that, search them. I suggest you learn more about javascript.